# How to store char array string to char-type pointer array? C++

Tags: c++

```
 //This is my logic

    int main() {
       char str1[];
       cin >> str1;
       int i = 0;
       int lengths1 = 0;
       while(str1[i] != '\0'){
       lengths1 ++;
       i++;
       }

       addString(str1, lengths1)
    }

    void addString(char str1[], int lengths1) {
       //How to store the strings to a 2d array?
}
```

Basically, I want to put char array strings into a 2d char array pointer to sort them.

My code will generate some char array string, and I want to store them in a 2d array whenever the string is generate, how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: use `std::string` and `std::vector`, then `std::sort`.

Comment: With all due respect, your code makes no sense. Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to achieve? What's the ultimate goal of this exercise? Show a [mcve].

Comment: for help with your cdoe you need to include a [mcve] and explain what is the problem. Currently your function `addString` tries to write to an array that is local to that function.... this code does not really help on explaining what you want to do

Comment: I want to store some string to an 2d char array.

Comment: Let me explain my question in a more detail way, my aim is to store a few c style string into a 2d array so I can sort those string by their length, I can only use iostream library.

Comment: You can start by actually declaring a 2D array. The shown code doesn't do anything of that sort. Do you know how to declare a 2D array? Furthermore, even the term "2D array" is mostly meaningless in C++. You have to specify what it is a 2D array of, in order to give any meaning. Additionally, the term "c style string into a 2d array" is also ambiguous. It could mean an array of C style strings, which would be a 2D array of chars, or a 2d array of C style strings, which would be a 3D array of chars. You need to be more specific as to exactly what your question is, it is completely unclear.

Comment: Sorry guys, i have to apologize that I raise an unclear question as I am new to here, I will try my best to make my question clearer.

Comment: Is this another "C with iostream" course, where you learn how to write legacy code? Please keep in mind that you should never write such code outside the course. Your teacher is wasting your time. C++ has evolved to a modern language.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The 2d char array is for storing the strings generated by the program. And later i want to sort the string in the 2d array.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, the course only allow me to use iostream, if they allow me to use other library, I am already done.

Comment: Ok, so why don't you start by actually declaring a "2d char array", because the shown code even fails to do that. Do you know how to declare a "2d char array"? If you don't, this should be explained in every C++ textbook, since this is pretty basic stuff. Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for your C++ textbook, so all basic questions of this nature will need to be referred to your textbook, for a full and complete explanation.

Comment: Do you know the sizes of the array a priori? Otherwise you'd need dynamic memory allocation but operators are declared in the header [new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). Are you allowed to use them?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // if you know the number of strings beforehead, you can use an array of strings.
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    std::string s3;

    //std::cin >> s1 >> s2 >> s3;

    // I'll assume these are the values.
    s1 = "cba";
    s2 = "bac";
    s3 = "abc";

    // the container that will contain the strings.
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    // to add a string to the container.
    v.push_back(s1);
    v.push_back(s2);
    v.push_back(s3);

    // use std::sort to sort the vector.
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

I think what you want is something like this. I'd suggest that you use `std::string` instead of `char[]`. Also use `std::vector` instead of the normal arrays.

If you really want to use `char[]`, you can write something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

void sort(char** strings, int sizeOfStrings)
{
    // some sorting algorithm.
}

int main()
{
    int numberOfStrings;
    std::cin >> numberOfStrings;

    char** strings = new char*[numberOfStrings];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++)
    {
        int lengthOfString;
        std::cin >> lengthOfString;
        // one additional character for the null terminator.
        strings[i] = new char[lengthOfString + 1];
        std::cin >> strings[i];
    }

    sort(strings, sizeOfStrings);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++)
        std::cout << strings[i] << '\n';

    // don't forget to free the allocated memory.

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++)
        delete strings[i];

    delete[] strings;
}
```

You can choose the sorting algorithm that you need. note that since you're using `char[]`, you'll have to use `strlen` to determine the size of each string, or you can store the size of the string along with the string in some way (possibly combine them in a struct).

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) is some of the sorting algorithms. This was the first search result when searching for `sorting algorithms`. I didn't read it and I don't know whether it's good or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i am not allow to use other library except iostream

Comment: @Kevin You should really mention such restrictions in the question, you can't expect everybody to sift through the comments.

Comment: I think you can't use `new` and `delete`. It's part of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new. OP is not allowed to use it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Do you suggest a better solution? I guess this way, everthing has to be known at complie time (the size of the array and the length of each string).

Comment: The whole assignment using C strings is wasted time. I wouldn't look for a good solution but for a simple solution with fixed sizes.